# Choosing source of light in case. LED stripes or cold cathodes?

Tags: case

I ordered a new case for my ITX build it's
[Phanteks Enthoo Evolv ITX (white)](http://www.phanteks.com/Enthoo-Evolv-ITX.html).

I want to light it with cold white light but I have to choose a source of light. I have two favourites (both powered by PSU):

- Cold Cathode (Revoltec) - one 300 mm at the top and one at the bottom of the case (if they will fit) or two 100 mm at the top and two at the bottom (if 300 mm won't fit).
- LED Strip (5050, 12V, Color: Cold White) - around the whole case or only at the top and bottom

And now questions:

1. Which configuration will consume less power (Watts)?
2. Which configuration provides more light?
3. Any pros/cons for this configurations?
4. Any other possible solutions?
5. Which will look better (I know it is subjective opinion, but what do you think)?

---

After using "Peter Zhu's" answer, I lit it with LED strips (3528, 12V, Color: Cold White) and below you can find a photo of it:

[image: Phanteks Enthoo Evolv ITX (white) with cold white LED stripes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really can't think of a reason to get cold cathodes, except maybe they produce more light than some LEDs. LEDs will always use less power as long as you are comparing it against a cold cathode with the same amount of light emitted. LEDs will also last longer than cold cathodes and are less fragile since they aren't in glass tubes. LEDs usually come in strips, so it is bendable which means that you can bend it around your case to get adequate lighting. Cold cathodes also require a inverter that converts your DC power to AC power, which is another source of inefficiency and point of failure. For looks, LEDs will look better because they are flexible but cold cathodes will give you a much more retro look.

Comment: Firstly thank you for answer. I assume you are right. If LED's are more reliable and consume less power I will use LED strips.

Comment: Totally totally 12v LEDs. 

Firstly, single colour LEDs are *ludiciously* cheap (I spent 5 dollars on a meter and half of LEDs for a unrelated issue).

Secondly, while you can get CCFL in  *one* colour, you have the option of RGB LEDS (which can switch colours).

You can also *trivially* wire up LEDs to a PC power supply without the need for an inverter.

Comment: Yeah, I brazed molex connector with led strip and connected it to my PSU. I wanted cold white light so I decided not to use RGB leds. In nearest future I want to connect it with brightness regulator which I will put outside case.