# Quiet 140 mm (black case + white propeller) case fans

Tags: cooling, quiet-computing

I'm looking for two kind of fans which I will mount in [Phanteks Enthoo Evolv ITX (white)](http://www.phanteks.com/Enthoo-Evolv-ITX.html). I'm looking for quitest fans meeting following requirements:

1. First one (back out fan): 

    - 140mm

    - black case

    - white proppeler

    - cold white led light

    - [example fan: Phanteks PH-F140SP LED](http://phanteks.com/PH-F140SP-LED.html)
2. Second one (2 x top out fans):

    - 140mm

    - black case

    - white proppeler

    - [example fan: Phanteks PH-F140XP](http://phanteks.com/PH-F140XP.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found other solution which was much cheaper:

- I resigned from using LED lighted fan because my case is lighted enough with LED stripes mounted inside it ([thread](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/choosing-source-of-light-in-case-led-stripes-or-cold-cathodes) about light in case).
- I found used (half year on 6V) fans from [NZXT Switch 810](https://www.nzxt.com/products/switch-810-white#product-reviews) which I bought for $5 each.
- I connected it to motherboard via [NZXT Grid+ V2](https://store.nzxt.com/products/grid-v2) and set them to work only when GPU/CPU will reach temperature above 50 °C.

I'm really happy with this solution when computer is idle it's really quiet and when I start to stress my PC fans are working on RPM dependent to temperatures.

---

If anyone is intrested in this setup I can post some photos on the weekend.